# How can I find the URL for a flash video in Firefox?

Tags: url

At [Nasul TV](http://www.nasul.tv/) is a TV recorded show, free.

I want to be able to find the URL for the video and then to use `wget` to download it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You probably need to install flash player from the software center to view videos online.

Comment: if in firefox go to addons and install video download helper then you can download it and most other videos too.

Answer (score 0):

More detail is needed. What do you mean by "viewing a link"? Normally you can find the link to video files in the page source, or via the Firebug network tab (if you don't have Firebug, you should get it). It should be something that ends in ".flv", or sometimes ".mp4", and once you have it it's easy to download: just open a terminal and type:

```
wget "http://www.nasul.tv/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/nasul1305.m4v" -O filename.m4v
```

(with the quotes).

Comment: I got Firebug but it didn't help. At that link above, there is a video. I'd like to have it's URL. isn't that something like http:..... ? There isn't any .flv there or .mp4, you could check for yourself.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? He asked how to use "uget" (which I assumed meant wget) to download it, that's what I'm providing instructions to do.

Comment: @user157244 are you actually talking about having the file on your computer to keep, or just watching in your browser? can you post the link to the page the video is on?

Comment: http://www.nasul.tv/  Here it is, I also posted it in the question. Of course I want to download it.

Comment: [link](http://www.nasul.tv)_italic_ **bold** 'code'

Comment: I don't understand this Markdown...the link was in my question

Comment: @user157244 So you mean the player on the homepage? I think I've found what you're after, the reason you couldn't find it was I was wrong about the extension. It wasn't flv or mp4, it was m4v.

Here is the URL: http://www.nasul.tv/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/nasul1305.m4v

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuu!!! Yes, it is .m4v, an Apple format as far as I read. Thank you both !!